# Looping an array of NSDictionaries in swift

Tags: ios, for-loop, swift, nsdictionary

Ok, trying to catch the last train to learn Swift, I have seen similar questions but I am not getting them to solve my issue.

I have an `NSDictionary` called `entries`, and one of the values, corresponding to key `"TYPES"` is an `NSArray` of NSDictionaries. I am trying to loop over this latter `NSDictionary` and retrieve an integer value for the key `"TID"`, I am doing:

```
for dict in entries["TYPES"] as NSDictionary {
   let tid : Int = typeDict["TID"]
}
```

But I am receiving as error: `(key: AnyObject, value: AnyObject)` does not have a member named 'subscript'

I understand this is due to `entries["TYPES"]` being `anyObject!` and comes from Xcode 6 beta 6, where a large number of Foundation APIs have been audited for optional conformance and hence need unwrapping but I have tried my best to unwrap without success, the compiler is always complaining a different thing. Someone knows how to do this?

Comment: Really consider a better data model than a dictionary with an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Yep, agreed, this is just for test and not the point here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this is a sample of your dictionary:

```
var entries: NSDictionary = [
    "TYPES": [
        [],
        ["TPD": 2],
        ["TID": 4]
    ] as NSArray
]
```

you have to:

- retrieve the element identified by the `TYPES` key, and attempt to cast as `NSArray`
- loop through all elements of the array
- attempt a cast of each element as `NSDictionary`
- check for the `TID` key existence, and read its value
- if the value is not nil, the search is over

This is the code:

```
var tid: Int?
if let types = entries["TYPES"] as? NSArray {
    for type in types {
        if let dict = types.lastObject as? NSDictionary {
            tid = dict["TID"] as? Int
            if tid != nil {
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running the code in a playground with the sample data, the output I see is `{Some 4}`.

However I would keep @Zaph's advice into account and model your data in a different way, using structs and/or classes

Comment: As I said above this is for test purposes only, and hey this works, I would try to understand this all even if, when Swift got out at WWDC 2014 someone tried to say code was going to be less then objective-c and right now doesn't sound like that. Anyway, thanks, really appreaciated!